# create a task for download from git in gradle?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have two projects. "App" and "Models". the project App I connect project Models

```
project(':models').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../models/app')
```

now everything is working
1. I downloaded the changes to git in Models
2. Build App project

how do I make the assembly App my project "Model" itself updated with git?

Answer (score 0):

You could make your gradle assembly task do a git pull I guess:

```
 assembly.doLast {
    exec {
        executable 'git'
        args = ['pull']
    }
}
```

I assume you will have to do some adjustments to this, maybe adding a working directory and some other arguments.